# MySQL Query from HTML form - can an input use wildcards?

Tags: php, mysql, user-input, wildcard

I've had a look, and while I've seen lots of explanations for using wildcards in the original PHP, I've not found anything to help me when the user input wants to use wildcards. I am very new to PHP and MYSQL. Which symbol should be used?

Basically, the user requests data from the MYSQL database for a given grade, which can be a simple number or a number followed by a letter, or a plus sign. I'd like them to be able to request specifically 6a (which works fine) or 6 followed by a wildcard to return 6a, 6a+, 6b etc (which I don't know how to do).

For further detail:

I have the following form:

```
<form name="gradereturn" method="POST" action="gradequery.php">
<input type="text" name="Grade" value="Grade">
<input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Retrieve">
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
$grade = $_POST['Grade'];
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
    mysql_connect("localhost", "**details**", "**details**") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("**details**") or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE Grade='$grade'") or die(mysql_error());  
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    echo "Line - Colour - Grade<br />";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['Line']. " - ". $row['Colour']. " - ". $row['Grade'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
else print ("Please enter your required grade above");
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: [MySQL wildcards](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` and make sure you escape `$grade` as well:

```
$grade = mysql_real_escape_string($grade);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE Grade LIKE '{$grade}'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

They can then specify `6` or `6%` or `6?` etc.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use the LIKE command.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM routes WHERE Grade LIKE '$grade%'")
```

This tells SQL to find all entries in `routes` where `Grade` starts with `$grade`.

For more information on `LIKE` - [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: did you mean `"SELECT * FROM routes WHERE Grade LIKE '{$grade}%'"`?

Comment: Yeah, no idea why I was concating a string within a string. Edit has been made.